# "Reloading" a Boost Timer bind to a class method

Tags: c++, boost

I've got some trouble with the asio timer.
It is bind to a class method, and when I reload the timer (each time I'm waiting for data or ack), the call back method is called (according to the boost spec).
The problem is that I don't know how to differentiate the cancelation or the completion of the timer.
How should I do that ?
Thanks !

```
const int TIMER_DURATION = 5000; // ms

tftp_connection::tftp_connection (std::string id,
                                  std::string file_name,
                                  connection_type_enum connection_type,
                                  tftp_server* server,
                                  boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
                : timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(TIMER_DURATION)) {
      //...

      // when sending a block and waiting for acknowledgement
        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(TIMER_DURATION));
        timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::timeout_callback , this));

//...
void tftp_connection::timeout_callback() {
    std::cout << "Time Out\n"; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to check the error code that can be given to the callback if you use the right callback function type. Have a look at:

[Boost async_wait example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer3.html)

Your callback should look somehow like this:

```
void tftp_connection::timeout_callback(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
    if(e.value() == ERROR_TIMEOUT) // Or whatever error code you want to check for.
    {
         std::cout << "Time Out\n";
    }
}
```

in addition, you need to change the bind to:

```
 timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::timeout_callback , this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

The boost::asio::placeholders::error tells the bind to create a function which can use the error code as an argument.

Comment: Probably you need to do the following:

    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::timeout_callback ,boost::asio::placeholders::error, this));
or
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::timeout_callback , this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul ! It's working fine with: timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&tftp_connection::timeout_callback , this,boost::asio::placeholders::error));